# How to use [Bind(Exclude="fieldName") in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, model-binding

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC 4 in Visual Basic, because we have an MVC section in our VB WebForms project. But all the tutorials online are in C#. Converting the C# code to VB is really testing my knowledge of VB (my skills in C# are rudimentary). I finally got stuck at this line of code in C#:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="CurrentPrice")] Models.Auction.auction)
```

I can't figure out how to add the [Bind] annotation to the same line in Visual Basic:

```
Function Create(ByVal auction As MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult
```

I've tried:

```
<Bind(Exclude="CurrentPrice")> _
Function Create(ByVal auction as MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult
```

which produces this error: Attribute 'BindAttribute' cannot be applied to 'Create' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

I've also tried this:

```
Function Create(ByVal <Bind(Exclude = "CurrentPrice")> auction As MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult
```

and this

```
Function Create(ByVal auction As <Bind(Exclude = "CurrentPrice")> MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult
```

In both cases, I get an 'identifier expected' error.

Does anyone know the proper VB syntax?

More generally, I haven't been able to find any good documentation on MSDN for VB syntax in MVC. Does anyone know where I could find good documentation for using VB with MVC?

Comment: You can try: `Function Create(<Bind(Exclude:="CurrentPrice")> test_auction As Models.Auction) As ActionResult`

Comment: The code that worked is:Function Create(<Bind(Exclude:="CurrentPrice")> ByVal test_auction As MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult. Thank you. Have you found any good MVC VB documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar question [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1467430.aspx?Convert+Bind+Attribute+from+C+to+VB).

It looks like what you need to do is:

```
Public Function Create(<Bind(Exclude := "CurrentPrice")> ByVal auction As MvcAuction.Auction) As ActionResult
```

Make sure to put the Bind before the "ByVal" and also use ":=" instead of "="